# Complex Variable Proof Check

Tags: complex-numbers

I have been stumped on this problem for a little bit, I figure that it's really simple and I'm missing something obvious, but I just wanted to see if what I have come up with is correct:

Let z and w be complex numbers such that |z|,|w|<1.  Prove that: $|\dfrac{z-w}{1-\bar{z}w}|<1$.

Here's my proof:
$|z-w|<1$, and $|\bar{z}w|=|\bar{z}||w|=|z||w|<1$, due to hypothesis.  Therefore: $|z-w|-|\bar{z}||w|<1\Longrightarrow |z-w|-|\bar{z}w|<1\Longrightarrow |z-w|<1+|\bar{z}w|<|1-\bar{z}w|\Longrightarrow |\dfrac{z-w}{1-\bar{z}w}|<1$

$\square$

Is this correct, is there some loophole that I'm missing, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: From $|z|\lt 1$ and $|w|\lt 1$ we cannot conclude that |z-w|\lt 1$.

Comment: To add to André's comment, try $z=0.5+0.5i$, $w=-0.5-0.5i$.

Comment: i see, thank you. any suggestions for tackling this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you know that $|z-w|<1$ to start with.

**Hint**.
$$\eqalign{\left|\frac{z-w}{1-\overline zw}\right|<1\quad
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad |z-w|<|1-\overline zw|\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad |z-w|^2<|1-\overline zw|^2\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad (z-w)(\overline z-\overline w)
    <(1-\overline zw)(1-z\overline w)\ .\cr}$$

Comment: This is the second part of the problem.  The first part of the problem is to prove that $|\frac{z-w}{1-\bar{z}w}|<1$ given that |z|,|w|<1

Comment: OK, see modified answer.

Comment: aha!!! great, thanks so much