# prove $|\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}|\lt1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> $z,a$ are both complex numbers. And $|z|\lt1,|a|\lt1$, prove $$|\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}|\lt1$$

I tried by denoting $z=x+yi,a=t+si$, and substitute them in $|\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}|$, but make it seems too sophisticated. So I am thinking about if there are ways more elegant to solve this by using some properties about complex number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $\left|\frac{\alpha - \beta}{1-\bar{\alpha}\beta}\right| < 1$ when $|\alpha|,|\beta| < 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506058/show-that-left-frac-alpha-beta1-bar-alpha-beta-right-1-when)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/734804, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1141986, ... – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7C%5Cfrac%7Bz-a%7D%7B1-%5Cbar%7Ba%7Dz%7D%7C%5Clt1%24&p=1)